# AltJS (Flux) + Typescript : Invalid action reference at bindListeners in store

Tags: typescript, flux

I implemented an example project exactly like [this](https://github.com/Shearerbeard/alt-typescript-tutorial) one but I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid action reference passed in`. This error is thrown at runtime in my store at:

```
        this.bindListeners({
            handleRefreshComponentLibrary: ComponentLibraryActions.refreshComponentLibrary,
            handleComponentLibraryRefreshed: ComponentLibraryActions.componentLibraryRefreshed,
            handleComponentLibraryRefreshFailed: ComponentLibraryActions.componentLibraryRefreshFailed
        });
```

The actions I'm referencing look like this:

```
interface Actions{
    refreshComponentLibrary():void;
    componentLibraryRefreshed(componentLibrary: MqtlComponent[]):void;
    componentLibraryRefreshFailed(errorMsg:string):void;
}

class ComponentLibraryActions extends AbstractActions implements Actions{

    constructor(){
        super(altInstance);
        this.generateActions(
            "refreshComponentLibrary",
            "componentLibraryRefreshed",
            "componentLibraryRefreshFailed"
        )
    }

    refreshComponentLibrary(){
        console.log("ACTION!!! Refresh comp library");
        this.dispatch();

        //Trigger async
        ComponentLibraryStore.fetchComponentsFromServer();

    }

    componentLibraryRefreshed(componentLibrary: MqtlComponent[]){
        console.log("Dispatch action: Library refreshed");
        this.dispatch(componentLibrary);
    }

    componentLibraryRefreshFailed(errorMsg: string){
        console.log("Dispatch action: Library refresh failed");
        this.dispatch(errorMsg);
    }
}

export = altInstance.createActio
```

Tried it without the this.generateActions(...) too, but no luck...

I'm not sure if my Actions are structurally the same as the alt.d.ts defines them but I'm doing it exactly like in the tutorial (which I assume is doing it right).

Any ideas? Is there an alternative for binding actions to stores?

Comment: I've had success with redux : https://github.com/TypeScriptBuilder/tsb/blob/master/docs/contributing/REDUX.md

Comment: @basarat Okay but it seems Alt cares about Typescript (they maintain the typings in their project), thats why I want to use it. Shouldn't be that hard?